# itext 7.0.1 PdfChoiceFormField missing characters

Tags: java, itext

In itext 7 if I use a unicode(times new roman) font in windows, the PdfTextFormField displays all characters correct. Even űőöüé etc.
But when i try to make a ComboBox field, with the option values:
  First
  Second
  Third,
Then in pdf the options will be:
  irs
  e on
  hir
If I use default font, the option dispay is ok, but obviously the űőöüé characters are trash.
Sample code:

```
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfChoiceFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfTextFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;

public class ComboTest {
    public static final String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/times.ttf";    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("combobox.pdf"));
            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
            String[] values = {"First","Second","Third"};
            PdfTextFormField text = PdfFormField.createText(
               pdfDoc,
               new Rectangle(72,200,108,26),
               "text", 
               "Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép",
               font,
               12.0f
            );
            PdfChoiceFormField combo = PdfFormField.createComboBox(
                pdfDoc,
                new Rectangle(36, 780, 108, 26),
                "combo",
                "Choose your poison",
                values
            );
            combo.setFontAndSize(font,12); 
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
            form.addField(combo); 
            form.addField(text);
            pdfDoc.close();
        } catch( Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

My question is just why?

Comment: That is realy curiouse. I tried it myself. If you change your default option from "Choose your poison" to "Second", then "Second" will be displayed correctly. Which IText Version do you use?

Comment: @GAlexMES 7.0.1, according to OP's question title.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thanks... :D

Comment: The only differenz I see is, that the Font you create is a [TrueTypeFont](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/io/font/TrueTypeFont.html) and the default Font of the PdfChoiceFormField is a [Type1Font](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/io/font/Type1Font.html)

Comment: It look likes an issue with font sub-setting. Only the glyphs required for the string `"Choose your poison"` are embedded, so `First Second Third` becomes `irs e on hir`.

Comment: Hmm. With Phantom Pdf the options are displayed correctly. Except the űő characters. My Acrobat Reader DC version is 15.023.2070.

Answer (score 0):

It seems mkl and GAlexMES found the answer.
http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/font-examples/itext7-can-i-embed-font-only-partially

If I choose CP1252 and embed ALL the font, it works.

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.CP1252);
font.setSubset(false);
```

The same won't work with unicode font.
Furthermore, if I use afm font instead of ttf, the pdf size would be much bigger, but at least readable.

Thanks.